# SSE: convert from const __m128 * to const float *

Tags: c++, floating-point, type-conversion, constants, sse

I'm trying to write a little SSE code but can't continue because of this error:

> error C2664: '_mm_loadu_ps' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const __m128 *' to 'const float *'

I've to load unaligned data and to convert into __m128 in order to use the SSE intrinsics functions.
I'm searching on the web but can't get this work.
Here's my code:

```
const Matrix<T> mul_SSE (const Matrix<T>& m)const{
    // ...
    __m128 a = _mm_loadu_ps((__m128 const*)&m(0,0)); //<-Here's the error line
    // ...
}
```

the parameter m is a matrix of floats.
Any suggestion? Thank you very much!

ps. Also if I write `__m128 a = _mm_loadu_ps((__m128*)&m(0,0));` it's giving me the same error:

> error C2664: '_mm_loadu_ps' : cannot convert parameter 1 from '__m128 *' to 'const float *'

SOLVED:
The right way:

```
__m128 a = _mm_loadu_ps(&m(0,0));
```

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation on MSDN states that _mm_loadu_ps takes a `float*` with 4 floats.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1b16s7z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

You need to pass in a `float*` pointing to an array of the floats in your matrix (4 actually).

You are casting a reference to your matrix to a `__m128 const*` when the function expects a `float*`.

Comment: First I used __m128 a = _mm_loadu_ps((__m128*)&m(0,0)); but it gets me the same error (cannot convert parameter 1 from '__m128 *' to 'const float *')..because of that I added const before __m128...

Comment: You're not supposed to be converting to an `__m128*`, but a `float*`. (Assuming your Matrix's members are conveniently ordered :v). You should probably manually build a float* with the data in your matrix. Allocate 16 bytes of memory and write the floats in order to that space.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! it made me realize that, like you said, I don't need to cast my data..in fact I'm reading an address which is not 16-byte aligned. Now in this way it works:__m128 a = _mm_loadu_ps(&m(0,0)); thank you! it's late and my vision is a little blurred.

Comment: You want to use aligned memory.  It makes a big difference in performance.  Just use _mm_malloc.